# Jython : Getting an com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.InvalidAttributeValException in Jython

Tags: python, jython

I am getting a syntax error in my code with Jython. Can anyone say what's wrong in the syntax? I am new to this language, don't have much of an idea.

Error Message :

### WASX7017E: Exception received while running file "namespace.jy"; exception information: com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.InvalidAttributeValException: ADMG0012E: The attribute value for attribute integration/endpoint/account is not valid.

My Code :

```
import sys

nodeName =sys.argv[0]
serverName =sys.argv[1]
profilePath=sys.argv[2]
machineName=sys.argv[3]

def createNamespaceBinding(nodeName,serverName,profilePath,machineName):
      print "Creating NamespaceBinding"
      ds = AdminConfig.getid("/Node:"+nodeName+"/Server:"+serverName+"/" )
      AdminTask.setJVMSystemProperties('[-serverName '+serverName+' -nodeName '+nodeName+' -propertyName  com.ibm.websphere.management.configservice.validatePropNames -propertyValue false]')
      AdminConfig.save()
      AdminConfig.create('StringNameSpaceBinding', ds, [['name', 'auditlogJmsConcurrency'],['nameInNameSpace', 'auditlogJmsConcurrency'], ['stringToBind', "4"]])
      AdminConfig.save()
      AdminConfig.create('StringNameSpaceBinding', ds, [['name', 'campaignStatisticsOutputDirectory'],['nameInNameSpace', 'campaignStatisticsOutputDirectory'], ['stringToBind', profilePath]])
      AdminConfig.save()
      AdminConfig.create('StringNameSpaceBinding', ds, [['name', 'cardImagepath'],['nameInNameSpace', 'cardImagepath'], ['stringToBind', profilePath]])
      AdminConfig.save()
      AdminConfig.create('StringNameSpaceBinding', ds, [['name', 'crmInputDirectory'],['nameInNameSpace', 'crmInputDirectory'], ['stringToBind', profilePath]])
      AdminConfig.save()
      AdminConfig.create('StringNameSpaceBinding', ds, [['name', 'crmOutputDirectory'],['nameInNameSpace', 'crmOutputDirectory'], ['stringToBind', profilePath]])
      AdminConfig.save()
      AdminConfig.create('StringNameSpaceBinding', ds, [['name', 'doAuditlog'],['nameInNameSpace', 'doAuditlog'], ['stringToBind', 'wm']])
      AdminConfig.save()
      AdminConfig.create('StringNameSpaceBinding', ds, [['name', 'elasticsearchClusterName'],['nameInNameSpace', 'elasticsearchClusterName'], ['stringToBind', machineName]])
      AdminConfig.save()
      AdminConfig.create('StringNameSpaceBinding', ds, [['name', 'elasticsearchHost'],['nameInNameSpace', 'elasticsearchHost'], ['stringToBind', machineName]])
      AdminConfig.save()
      AdminConfig.create('StringNameSpaceBinding', ds, [['name', 'elasticsearchIndexName'],['nameInNameSpace', 'elasticsearchIndexName'], ['stringToBind', 'pegasus2']])
      AdminConfig.save()
      AdminConfig.create('StringNameSpaceBinding', ds, [['name', 'elasticsearchPort'],['nameInNameSpace', 'elasticsearchPort'], ['stringToBind', '9300']])
      AdminConfig.save()
      AdminConfig.create('StringNameSpaceBinding', ds, [['name', 'iframeIntegrationTestApplicationBaseUrlOnThePegasusSideOfProxy'],['nameInNameSpace', 'iframeIntegrationTestApplicationBaseUrlOnThePegasusSideOfProxy'], ['stringToBind', 'http://DCR4VM:8080/misys/']])
      AdminConfig.save()
      AdminConfig.create('StringNameSpaceBinding', ds, [['name', 'NetbankSrvURL'],['nameInNameSpace', 'NetbankSrvURL'], ['stringToBind', 'iiop://localhost:2814']])
      AdminConfig.save()
      AdminConfig.create('StringNameSpaceBinding', ds, [['name', 'pegasusLogbackCorexmlUrl'],['nameInNameSpace', 'pegasusLogbackCorexmlUrl'], ['stringToBind', 'file:'+profilePath+'\logs\logbackMain.xml']])
      AdminConfig.save()
      AdminConfig.create('StringNameSpaceBinding', ds, [['name', 'pegasusSsoProviderRetrievePrincipalUrl'],['nameInNameSpace', 'pegasusSsoProviderRetrievePrincipalUrl'], ['stringToBind', 'http://localhost:9085/foundation-guiwar/pegasus/ssoprovider/retrievePrincipal']])
      AdminConfig.save()
      AdminConfig.create('StringNameSpaceBinding', ds, [['name', 'integration/endpoint/account'],['nameInNameSpace', 'integration/endpoint/account'], ['stringToBind', 'http://localhost:9085/backend-emulator-war']])
      AdminConfig.save()
      AdminConfig.create('StringNameSpaceBinding', ds, [['name', 'integration/endpoint/card'],['nameInNameSpace', 'integration/endpoint/card'], ['stringToBind', 'http://localhost:9085/backend-emulator-war']])
      AdminConfig.save()
      AdminConfig.create('StringNameSpaceBinding', ds, [['name', 'integration/endpoint/chequebook'],['nameInNameSpace', 'integration/endpoint/chequebook'], ['stringToBind', 'http://localhost:9085/backend-emulator-war']])
      AdminConfig.save()
      AdminConfig.create('StringNameSpaceBinding', ds, [['name', 'integration/endpoint/customer'],['nameInNameSpace', 'integration/endpoint/customer'], ['stringToBind', 'http://localhost:9085/backend-emulator-war']])
      AdminConfig.save()
      AdminConfig.create('StringNameSpaceBinding', ds, [['name', 'integration/endpoint/investment'],['nameInNameSpace', 'integration/endpoint/investment'], ['stringToBind', 'http://localhost:9085/backend-emulator-war']])
      AdminConfig.save()
      AdminConfig.create('StringNameSpaceBinding', ds, [['name', 'integration/endpoint/loan'],['nameInNameSpace', 'integration/endpoint/loan'], ['stringToBind', 'http://localhost:9085/backend-emulator-war']])
      AdminConfig.save()
      AdminConfig.create('StringNameSpaceBinding', ds, [['name', 'integration/endpoint/notificationsettings'],['nameInNameSpace', 'integration/endpoint/notificationsettings'], ['stringToBind', 'http://dcr4vm:9084/OnlineInvestmentWS']])
      AdminConfig.save()
      AdminConfig.create('StringNameSpaceBinding', ds, [['name', 'integration/endpoint/productlist'],['nameInNameSpace', 'integration/endpoint/productlist'], ['stringToBind', 'http://localhost:9085/backend-emulator-war']])
      AdminConfig.save()
      AdminConfig.create('StringNameSpaceBinding', ds, [['name', 'integration/endpoint/standingorder'],['nameInNameSpace', 'integration/endpoint/standingorder'], ['stringToBind', 'http://localhost:9085/backend-emulator-war']])
      AdminConfig.save()
      AdminConfig.create('StringNameSpaceBinding', ds, [['name', 'integration/endpoint/statement'],['nameInNameSpace', 'integration/endpoint/statement'], ['stringToBind', 'http://localhost:9085/backend-emulator-war']])
      AdminConfig.save()
      AdminConfig.create('StringNameSpaceBinding', ds, [['name', 'integration/endpoint/termdeposit'],['nameInNameSpace', 'integration/endpoint/termdeposit'], ['stringToBind', 'http://localhost:9085/backend-emulator-war']])
      AdminConfig.save()
      AdminConfig.create('StringNameSpaceBinding', ds, [['name', 'integration/endpoint/transaction'],['nameInNameSpace', 'integration/endpoint/transaction'], ['stringToBind', 'http://localhost:9085/backend-emulator-war']])
      AdminConfig.save()
      AdminConfig.create('StringNameSpaceBinding', ds, [['name', 'integration/endpoint/transfer'],['nameInNameSpace', 'integration/endpoint/transfer'], ['stringToBind', 'http://localhost:9085/backend-emulator-war']])
      AdminConfig.save()

#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
# Main program
#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
createNamespaceBinding(nodeName,serverName,profilePath,machineName)
```

I have added call to setJVMSystemProperties(), so it will ignore '/' in the name attribute, but am still facing the problem.

Comment: @martineau please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: Some one please help me out to resolve this issue

Comment: It worked for  after adding this property file com.ibm.websphere.management.configservice.validateNames  = false    and then stopping and starting the server and then try to run jython script for namespace binding